# Is int 0x80 is the only interrupt number used in linux assembly programming?

Tags: linux, assembly, int

Do we use only 80H in assembly programming to request a service to linux kernel?

what is the utility of other interrupt numbers in linux?

I am transitioning from windows to linux.

Comment: Which interrupts do you use on *Windows*?

Comment: it is the software interrupt, what else do you need?
and worth to mention that syscall/sysenter is used on modern machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int3` (the debug breakpoint) and `int 80h` (old system call) are the two software interrupts commonly used on linux. Hardware interrupts are used by device drivers, but those probably don't concern you.

That said, on 32 bit systems the kernel provides code mapped into each process that can be invoked to perform a system call and it will use the most appropriate mechanism automatically (`syscall`, `sysenter` or `int 80h`). Since all 64 bit systems support the `syscall` instruction, that's the one normally used in long mode. Note that 64 bit system call numbers differ from 32 bit.

Finally, you don't typically use system calls from assembly on linux. You either use the c library or avoid system calls entirely because they are slow and one of the main uses of assembly is for speed. There are exceptions of course, such as security-related code or compiler/language development.

Comment: The last paragraph is false. Every thing in Linux is done through these system calls.

Comment: `32 bit systems` is irrelevant, imho

Comment: @BSH: The last paragraph is true - typically the small amount of the code worth optimising in assembly doesn't use system calls, and the system calls are only used by the larger amount of the code (where it's not worth bothering with assembly).

Comment: @Brendan The last paragraph is false, in the context of the question! We are talking about the assembly programming here. And Linux is a heaven for the assembly programmer, because every OS functionality can be reached through int 80h. (-1 for the last paragraph)

Comment: Yes you can use syscalls, but just because you can it doesn't necessarily make sense to do so (just try some networking code). I maintain the last paragraph in the sense Brendan explained (thanks!).

Comment: @Jester: I have Linux network programs (for example [this one](http://chiselapp.com/user/johnfound/repository/phWeb/index)), that use exactly int 80h and programming such application is pretty easy and straight-forward.

Comment: When you call C's `printf()`, it internally calls `write()` and ultimately does `sys_write` system call and the kernel takes it from there, system calls are the only interface you have.

Comment: @BSH nobody argued that. I just said you don't code syscalls in assembly, because it usually makes no sense. If you use syscalls that probably means you lost any speed advantage already, so you might as well use something more high level. Except if your name is John :)

Comment: So, if I want to write fast Assembly code, your saying don't interact directly with the OS, but call an external library that at the end of the day calls the OS functions?  Yeah, makes sense.

Comment: @Gunner First option, use high level language. Second option, if you absolutely need asm, use a library. Asm is tedious and non-portable, use it only for the parts where you get significant advantage.